# How to detect the event when smart card scanned

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, smartcard, rfid

I am working on **smartcard** based application with smartcard reader, here whenever I flash the card i should get the card UID, based on that I need to retrieve the details from database.

For this need how do i start, whether i need to create service on windows which always run background **or** is there a way to detect an event on OS **or** any scheduler program.

I am able to get UID and related but i need to run the program externally.

Please suggest me on this issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid, that this question is not tagged in a way, that people knowing the solution will find it. I'll add the windows tag, since the smart card specific problems are solved and only the OS problem  remains.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a USB or serial connection  to connect your card reader to pc, .you can use datareceived event of Serial port class.